# Create a sequence column in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a column with names and i wanted to add a column that count the sequence of each row based on the name. So if a name appears multiple time (i.e 4), the first row of that name will have sequence 1 and the 2nd row sequence 2, etc...

```
Name        Sequence    
Andrew       1    
Andrew       2    
Andrew       3    
Paul         1    
Amy          1    
Amy          2    
Jean         1
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use COUNTIF with a variable range:

```
=COUNTIF($A$1:A2,A2)
```

[image]

Comment: @user3139937 mark as answered please, if this solves your problem.