# Numbering occurrences by ID and Date in Excel

Tags: excel

I'm trying to assign occurrences of assessments to a column of students in Excel. Not all students take the same amount of assessments and they do so in different windows (transfer students).

I want a students first assessment to be marked as '1'. Currently they're only marked with their Window values (Summer = 1 to Spring = 4). As shown in the first table. I'm using an INDEX-MATCH for this.

**Question:** How do I assign the correct occurrence of each test using the Date and ID columns in Excel?

The first two students (ID 1, ID2) are correct. The final two students (ID 3, ID4) should look like the second table.

```
ID   Date     Test #   Window 
 1    6/5/2018    1    Summer
 1    9/7/2018    2    Fall 
 1    2/9/2019    3    Winter 
 2    6/5/2018    1    Summer
 2    9/8/2018    2    Fall 
 2    2/8/2019    3    Winter 
 2    4/4/2019    4    Spring
 3    9/8/2018    2    Fall 
 3    2/8/2019    3    Winter 
 3    4/7/2019    4    Spring
 4    2/5/2019    3    Winter 
 4    4/9/2019    4    Spring
```

Ideal state for ID 3 & ID 4

```
ID   Date     Test #   Window 
 3    9/8/2018    1    Fall 
 3    2/8/2019    2    Winter 
 3    4/7/2019    3    Spring
 4    2/5/2019    1    Winter 
 4    4/9/2019    2    Spring
```

Comment: Why not use `COUNTIF` with the ID as criterion, and a variable range? See [Create a sequence column in excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52171832/create-a-sequence-column-in-excel/52171873#52171873), which illustrates the principle.

Comment: How does the date matter? currently it looks like you are counting based on the ID only.

Comment: The date matters because of when assessments are taken throughout the year. So an assessment in Winter (2/5/19) could be one students third test and another first test. It might not matter for the formula though, I just assumed it would.

Comment: If the data is always sorted it does not matter, but if the data is not always sorted then yes we need to include it.  Is the data always sorted?

Comment: It doesn't start sorted, but that's something I can do. That sequence column worked perfectly once I sorted by ID and Date.

Comment: @ReedRawlings do you want a formula that takes date into consideration so it does not need to be sorted?

Comment: If not I will close this as a duplicate.

Comment: @ScottCraner that would be really useful as others who work in this document will inevitably sort in different formats

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

```
=COUNTIFS(A:A,A2,B:B,"<" & B2)+1
```

It will be independent of sorting, but it assumes the date is unique to the ID:

[image]

Comment: Slightly different from what I was thinking... `=COUNTIFS(A:A,A2,B:B,"<="&B2)`

Comment: Yeah yours is good too, I was just curious if we'd come up with the same thing.